# 500 internal server error while using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

In my php application while using ajax , i was wanted to delete an id .it's getting csrf_token as request but not giving any response.

//JS script is here

```
function deleteData() {

 var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

           $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('deleting')}}" + "/" + id,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    '_method': 'DELETE',
                    '_token': csrf_token
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    table1.ajax.reload();
                    swal({
                        title: "Information Deleted Successfully!",
                        text: "You did a good job!",
                        icon: "success",
                        button: "Great !",
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    swal({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Something went wrong!',
                        timer: "3000"
                    });
                }

            })

        } else {
            swal("Your informatiion is safe!");
        }
    });
```

}

//laravel route is here

```
 Route::delete('/deleting/{id}','CgpaController@delete');
```

//Laravel controller method is here

```
public function destroy($id) {
     StudentInfo::destroy($id); 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs in storage?

Comment: Always check the laravel.log file under storage folder (or logs folder on old versions)

Comment: Actually i am very new to laravel or php.so please help me out.

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log`; check that file for any errors. 500 Server Error is a generic error for a number of things that can go wrong, so check that file for the full error and add it to your question.

Comment: If it's a 500, then I strongly suggest you check your log file as Tim Lewis suggested. Also, I am not able to get this part - {{url('deleting')}} when you mention the url. How are you able to get a Laravel function inside a JS block?

Comment: @AmitavRoy If the `<script>` tag is inside a `.blade.php` file, you can use `{{ }}` (blade syntax). If the file was a stright `js` file, like `script.js`, then you cannot.

Comment: @TimLewis ok, you didn't mention it was inside blade and hence I wanted to confirm. But yes, even now do check the laravel.log file and see what's the error.

Comment: the script is in a blade.php file that's why i was used {{}} this.

Comment: @AmitavRoy Yeah, they didn't explicitly say it was a `.blade.php` file, and I seen questions where people have tried to use `{{ }}` inside a JS file and it didn't work, so no harm in confirming :)

Comment: @MsMRobin Add the code for `public function delete()` to your question (do not post it as a comment), and the error in your log; until you do, no one can help you with this issue.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you very much.

Comment: @MsMRobin First thing that comes to mind is you're missing the import of `StudentInfo`; do you have `use App\StudentInfo;` (or `use App\Models\StudentInfo;` if it's in a subfolder) at the top of your controller?

Comment: @TimLewis Brother you tried a lot to help me.Thank you very much Brother. I found the solution.You can see my ans is given below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone. I found the error.I was using laravel's restful API(resource controller) where a method called destroy was doing the task . But i didn't mentioned destroy method in my route.
The route will be like this after correction.

```
Route::delete('/deleting/{id}','CgpaController@destroy');
```